# Showing difference between values with color in a bar graph

Tags: color, charts

I have a bar chart for probabilities of getting a score in a dice game with unfair dice, need to show how probabilities vary with score and don't just constantly go up. I thought color would be a good way to do this.

So I tried to look up how to directly change colors of bars on a bar graph and found posts saying you couldn't, that you had to use a color scheme.  Alright I thought, that will work, I need the higher probabilities on this chart to look different from the lower so a heatmap theme would work, but it turns out, theme only changes the bars by x position.

How do I make the color change based on Y values?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are looking for `ColorFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

This will color your bar with the hue defined by the value of each bar:

```
BarChart[
 Table[
  {Style[zz = RandomReal[], FaceForm[Hue[zz]]]}, {20}]]
```

Comment: It's a new feature of 11.1?

Comment: No.  I'm running v. 10.4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option `ColorFunction` (as suggested by swish in the comments) or `Style` each data point with a color that depends on its `Rescaled` value:

```
SeedRandom[123]
d = RandomInteger[10, 10];

Row[{BarChart[d, ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 400],
  BarChart[Style[#, Hue[Rescale[#, MinMax @ d]]] & /@ d, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

If you use a named color gradient like `"Rainbow"` you can change the range of the color gradient to `MinMax @ d` using `ColorData[{"Rainbow", MinMax @ d}]`:

```
Row[{BarChart[d, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 400], 
  BarChart[Style[#, ColorData[{"Rainbow", MinMax @ d}]@#] & /@ d, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]